# Swift button frame height issue (viewDidLayoutSubviews)

Tags: ios, swift

I've got some square buttons that I'd like to add rounded corners to that are proportional to the button's height. In past versions of my app, I had implemented this feature without issues using viewDidLayoutSubviews(). For some reason, after pushing a new version of my app with other features I had tweaked, this section of code no longer functions as expected. Here is the code:

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {

for button in buttons {

button!.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

button!.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)

button!.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4

button!.layer.shadowRadius = button!.frame.height / 40

button!.layer.cornerRadius = button!.frame.height / 10

}
```

Again, this block of code used to work just fine but for some reason it no longer works. What I am experiencing is much larger relative radii on smaller buttons (iPhone SE) compared to bigger buttons (iPads).

To troubleshoot, in viewDidLayoutSubviews(), I'm printing the button!.frame.height and I'm noticing that no matter what device I use the frame height is 395.5, which I believe is the correct size only on the 12.9" iPad. Therefore, the buttons look correct on the 12.9" iPad but the radii end up being too large on all of the smaller devices.

Any idea what's going on here? Why is it that they're all returning the same frame height even though they're visually very different sizes on the different devices?

Comment: Where's your call to `super. viewDidLayoutSubviews()`? That should be the first line of code here.

Comment: What sets the size of the buttons? Are they setup with constraints? Are the buttons sized correctly on the smaller devices? Is the problem only with the corner radius?

Comment: @rmaddy, adding super.viewDidLayoutSubviews() did not solve. The button sizes are setup with constraints, yes, and they are always sized correctly. The only issue is the corner radius.

Comment: I've confirmed that when it is setting the radii, it believes all of the buttons have a frame height of 395.5 which is only true for the 12.9" iPad. I'm having trouble understanding why this is the case for all of the over devices.

Comment: More weird information - I copy and pasted the above code into the viewWillAppear() method and the problem was resolved. I then deleted the code from viewWillAppear(), leaving me with my original code during posting of question, and it is continuing to run as expected (working). What could possibly be the cause of this intermittent behavior?

Answer (score 0):

> I copy and pasted the above code into the viewWillAppear() method and
>   the problem was resolved. I then deleted the code from
>   viewWillAppear(), leaving me with my original code during posting of
>   question, and it is continuing to run as expected (working). What
>   could possibly be the cause of this intermittent behavior

The reason when you initialized the buttons in `viewWillAppear` and remove them but it still work because your button's frame did not change in the `viewDidLayoutSubview` method. And the `viewDidLayoutSubview` is invoked only controller's view is updated, rotated, or changed, which in your case it does not.

If you try to rotate your device you will see your parent view's frame changed.

For more information about view hierarchy. See this [article](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UIViewController/viewWillLayoutSubviews)

Answer (score 0):

```
Try like this:-

    override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
    super.viewDidLayoutSubviews()

    for button in buttons {

    button!.layer.shadowColor = UIColor.black.cgColor

    button!.layer.shadowOffset = CGSize(width: 0, height: 1.0)

    button!.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.4

    button!.layer.shadowRadius = button!.frame.height / 40

    button!.layer.cornerRadius = button!.frame.height / 10

    }
```